# Heliocentric to barycentric coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I have a system with a central body and "particles" orbiting around it. The system is described in heliocentric coordinates. I am trying to obtain the velocity of the central body in barycentric coordinates, how do I do that ?

I have the position and velocity of the center of mass in heliocentric coordinate system.

Apparently I can't just use minus the speed of the barycenter in heliocentric coordinates.

I know I have to use the fact that in a barycentric frame the sum of all linear momentum contributions is 0.

Comment: see http://www.astrosurf.com/jephem/astro/ephemeris/et520transfo_en.htm

Answer (score 2):

For sol (our sun) and the Earth (**only**) the heliocentric and barycentric coordinates are [almost the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Primary%E2%80%93secondary_examples), if you intend to include all the objects in our solar system (or calculate for a different solar system) it gets far more [complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_celestial_reference_system#Purpose_and_implementation):

[image: Barycenter]

Using a software package such as [astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/index.html) and writing a [few lines of code](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/generated/examples/coordinates/plot_galactocentric-frame.html#sphx-glr-generated-examples-coordinates-plot-galactocentric-frame-py) one can easily make such calculations accurately; utilizing the CODATA2018 physical constants, correct true or mean barycentric ecliptic frames, time dilation, etc. Complete [documentation](http://learn.astropy.org/) explains how to make various astrophysical calculations. It is [used by dozens](https://www.astropy.org/affiliated/index.html) of software programs.

A book on the subject, [Spherical Astronomy](https://books.google.ca/books?id=wOpaUFQFwTwC&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=Heliocentric%20to%20barycentric%20coordinates&source=bl&ots=D2QLLnybFE&sig=ACfU3U0WvoMI5Xm8HMK0Lk2qglCQsV_80w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK3aSr2c_kAhVXuZ4KHWTUC7QQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Heliocentric%20to%20barycentric%20coordinates&f=false) by Robin Micheal Green, explains the answer to your question in just under 2 dozen pages.

Answer (score -1):

I would work out your barycentric co-ord first, then compare them with a matrix subtraction and normalisation (Most efficient in code).
This would give you a vector multiplier to from 0-1 (percentage) per component.

Next work out the maximum velocity in each dimension given the maximum offset.
Then simply times your normalised components by this velocity.